Is there a way to remember a property change of a deeply nested object
Is there a way to trigger recomposition when a single property of an object changes in compose?  I know remember { mutableStateOf(x) }  won't work as the object reference remains the same.  I know this could be solved by using the .copy() method to update the property and the object reference, however, the property is only ever modified inside of the object (in a separate module), but needs to be read outside of it.
UI Code in question:
val sp = SharedState.state.processor.rememberSp()
...
Text("Stack pointer is $sp")

SharedState.state is a singleton object containing persistant objects for the program.  
.processor is an instance of the Processor class, part of which is show below.
Processor class:
class Processor(...) {
    val stackptr: UInt get() = stack.ptr //readonly property
    private val stack = Stack(memory, stackRange.last - stackRange.first, stackRange.first) //internal class
    @Composable inline fun rememberSp() = currentComposer.cache(currentComposer.changed(stackptr)) { stackptr } //tried
    @Composable inline fun rememberSp2() = remember(stackptr) { stackptr } //tried
    @Composable inline fun rememberSp3() = remember { mutableStateOf(stackptr) } //tried  
    ...
}

none of these methods serve to allow ui recomposition of the stack.ptr property.

the only thing that can trigger updates in compose is a change of a mutable state object

I solved the issue by adding update functions to mutate the ui.
